# Is the world destroyed in Brazil?

Tags: brazil

In the movie *Brazil*, there's a scene where they're driving down a highway and it's padded on both sides by very tall billboards.

The camera pans and the entire landscape behind the billboards are barren.

[image]

Is the world supposed to be apocalyptic?

Comment: Is this scene right at the end of the movie? After the interrogation?

Comment: @DJClayworth
I believe it's earlier, Scene 86 in the official script (https://sfy.ru/?script=brazil), in the scenes before they get caught.

Comment: But it then makes way into an idyllic countryside...

Answer (score 3):

The film is often referred to as a 'dystopian satire" (e.g. J. Scalzi); but, it is certainly apocalyptic in some manner. The world is not destroyed in the film though--unless you mean figuratively (because it is dystopian). Gilliam himself is quoted as saying: "'I always thought the ending was chilling, but then it bursts out musically and suddenly it's wonderful -- wonderful in the context of all the possibilities open to our boy -- at least he's free in his mind" (p. 77 -- 'The Cinema of Terry Gilliam: It's a Mad World', Eds J. Birkenstein, A. Froula, K. Randell).